# Visual Studio Сode doesn't see a tilde (~) in an absolute path

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

I deployed a project and I have a lot of file imports from the root directory. Here they are implemented like this:

```
import { Link, Router } from "~/routes";
```

But VSC doesn't see the tilde and doesn't access files. If I replace the "~" with "@", the problem is solved. But I cannot make this change a thousand times:

```
import { Link, Router } from "@/routes";
```

How do I make VSC react to the "~" like a "@" and import the files?

Comment: "But I cannot make this change a thousand times:" - why can't you? There's a perfectly workable search-and-replace-in-multiple-files feature in VS Code. Just replace `from "~/` with `from "@/` ...

Comment: @AKX I need the paths to remain with a tilde in the import

Comment: Neither @ nor ~ seem to be standard JS so maybe you need the correct VCS plugin to recognise them (if one exists)

Comment: @Alexander Why do you need that, if it doesn't work?

Comment: @AKX it works for all other people who work on the project

Comment: Maybe ask those other people how they've configured their VSC then :)

Comment: `~` in paths is typically a reserved character. It doesn't map to a real location but it's expanded to user's home directory by certain tools. As already mentioned, you're probably using some third-party framework for which you don't have a Visual Studio Code extension.

Comment: @AKX they use Webstorm

Answer (score 0):

try to update the webpack config, this is the way how `@` character works

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: what i did wrong? My code in html. Its next.config.js file https://codepen.io/kava13/pen/BapBWZR

Comment: @Alexander `@` is also an alias, use `src` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line in the root of `settings.json` in vs code:

`"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",`

Hovering over this configuration you'll get the tooltip:
*Prefers a non-relative import based on the baseUrl or paths configured in your jsconfig.json / tsconfig.json.*

So make sure you add this to your `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` as well. For example:

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"],
    },
  },
}
```